# The Breaker: Season Three

Tags: the-breaker

Does anyone know if there is actually going to be a third season in the manga? I know they took a break [LOL] from the Breaker series, but I've seen rumours flying about that they might be going back to it.

Is this baseless rumour?

Comment: Welcome to A&M! In the future questions, kindly include the source of the rumors as well, it can help determine if a rumor is 'baseless', and help us determine if it actually is announced. As Unannounced future events are considered off-topic here

Comment: Oh sorry! Will remember to do so next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there will be a continuation. However, it's going to take a few more years until it releases. As Jeon Geuk-Jin & Jin-Hwan mentioned during [their inverview with Star Comics](https://anime.everyeye.it/notizie/the-breaker-intervista-autori-manhwa-edito-star-comics-403871.html) in October 2019.

The interview is originally in Italian, but below I have included a google translated edition as well

> Star Comics : Is this the first time you are interviewed by Italian journalists?
>
> GJ JH : Yes, we have been interviewed by many Europeans, but never by the Italians.
>
> SC: What was the idea behind the work ?
>
> GJ JH: Usually in manhwa there are themes that are easily understood by Orientals, which are difficult for Westerners to understand. We wanted to make these issues accessible to a public outside of Korean soil.
>
> SC: Given the incredible details, both in history and in drawings, how long does it take to create a volume?
>
> GJ JH: During the first series we had about 4 months to publish each volume, while for the second series we had more or less 3 months.
>
> SC: How do you create locations that perfectly recreate the atmosphere of some places?
>
> GJ : Living in Seoul, during the walks I take pictures and send them to Jin-Hwan who manages to recreate them in a very faithful way.
>
> SC : Are there some moments you like to remember?
>
> GJ JH : It is very pleasant to think about how the opera fans welcomed us in different countries, especially in France.
>
> SC : Is it possible to have some details on the third season?
>
> GJ JH : **We can only say that it will be released in a few years**.
>
> SC : Between the first and second season there was a profound change in the protagonist, who became more mature. Is that why in the second series you didn't see the same passion or sexual transport present instead in the first one?
>
> GJ JH : Actually, changing companies, we were advised to limit some scenes to make it accessible to a wider audience.